# Multiple database schemas in Rails 3 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any to specify a different schema for an ActiveRecord model in Rails 3? The following used to work in Rails 2:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "hr.company"
end
```

This fails in Rails 3 with the message `Table myapp.hr.company doesn't exist`.

The following works for simple models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "hr"
  set_table_name "company"
end
```

The problem with this approach is twofold: first, Rails creates a separate database connection for this model, imposing an additional overhead. Second, all queries are now invoked in the context of this connection, meaning that any joins back to the `myapp` schema will break:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "hr"
  set_table_name "company"
  has_many :widgets # widgets table resides in myapp schema
end
```

This in turn will fail with `Table hr.widgets doesn't exist`.

So, is there any way to achieve this in Rails 3?

Comment: Just to clarify... do you just want to temporarily change the table name or permanently change the table name?

Comment: Permanently, as in, the qualified table name should always be used for this model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use abstract class and inherit from it:

**app/models/db.rb**

```
class Db < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :db
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

**app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < Db
  set_table_name :notes
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

**config/database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000


db:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/db.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

In db.sqlite3 there is only `notes` table.